# Static dispatch in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

Does this code here use static dispatch or dynamic dispatch?

```
public class Survey
{
    public void DoSurvey()
    {
        System.out.println("DoSurvey is called");
    }
}


Survey survey = new Survey();
survey.DoSurvey();
```

Because Java uses dynamic dispatch for all methods except private, final and static, the method to be called is still decided at runtime, which means the object that is assigned to the reference *survey* is examined at runtime and the correct method is called. Still, early binding is used which means that the compiler has the type of the reference *survey* and can check whether it is even legal to call the function. Then the function is dynamically dispatched at runtime when the nature of the underlying object is checked. Is my understanding right? Also what is an example where static dispatch is used?

Comment: What's static in above? It's an example of dynamic dispatch. Add static keyword after public and see the magic accross your implementations. Btw C# != java

Comment: I corrected the post, my mistake. See now.

Answer (score 2):

This ugly code (static methods are called via variables) displays some static-ish dispatch:

```
public class Parent {
    public static void statictest(){System.out.println("Parent.statictest");}
    public void test(){System.out.println("Parent.test");}
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public static void statictest(){System.out.println("Child.statictest");}
    public void test(){System.out.println("Child.test");}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c=new Child();
    Parent p=c;
    c.test();
    p.test();
    c.statictest();
    p.statictest();
}
```

will result in

```
Child.test
Child.test
Child.statictest
Parent.statictest
```

However I would not dare claim "that is static dispatch, period", since I have not thought over what would happen in case of overloading, especially when signatures solely differ in argument types which are related to each other (so one inherits from another).

Comment: How is this not pure static dispatch? The static method that is called can be decided in compile time based on the type of the object that it is called on. That is static dispatch. And when calling test, dynamic dispatch occurs because the implementation of the method that is called is decided in runtime, and that's the reason why calling test on p results in printing Child.test (because the actual object is Child and dynamic dispatching calls the test method provided in Child).

Comment: Can you elaborate more, I don't seem to understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: @LearningMath yes, this is static dispatch. What I meant was what I wrote: I did not think through all possible (ab)uses of inheritance, interfaces and overloading, and this was just one example snippet which is not even "good" code.